# Error code 13, message: An internal error occurred. When deploying to App Engine using terraform

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to create a new terraform project as simple as possible that should create an app engine application and deploy a hello world node.js app.

My repository:
https://github.com/Leejjon/ts-appengine-terraform

I can run my https://github.com/Leejjon/ts-appengine-terraform/blob/main/terraform/main.tf file with "terraform apply" and it creates all resources just fine, until I add the actual google_app_engine_standard_app_version, which will fail with:

```
google_app_engine_standard_app_version.app_v2: Creating...
google_app_engine_standard_app_version.app_v2: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
google_app_engine_standard_app_version.app_v2: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
google_app_engine_standard_app_version.app_v2: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
╷
│ Error: Error waiting to create StandardAppVersion: Error waiting for Creating StandardAppVersion: Error code 13, message: An internal error occurred.
│
│   with google_app_engine_standard_app_version.app_v2,
│   on main.tf line 80, in resource "google_app_engine_standard_app_version" "app_v2":
│   80: resource "google_app_engine_standard_app_version" "app_v2" {
│
╵
```

Steps to reproduce:

- Clone my repo https://github.com/Leejjon/ts-appengine-terraform
- Set up a GCP account.
- Create a project in GCP.
- Install and configure the gcloud CLI
- Install terraform
- Comment out line 8-12 in main.tf to just use a local terraform statefile (using a bucket for it is not needed for this reproduction scenario)
- Run npm install in the app folder.
- Run terraform apply inside of the terraform folder

I did verify that I am able to deploy the app using the app.yaml file by running "gcloud app deploy --version=x" inside the app folder:
https://github.com/Leejjon/ts-appengine-terraform/blob/main/app/app.yaml

However, it's quite unclear to me what the gcloud app deploy command does under the hood, and how I can replicate that using terraform.

My terraform project is based on:

- The terraform app engine docs https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/app_engine_application.html
- The google cloud terraform docs: https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/resource-management/store-state
- This example https://github.com/nearform/gcp-articles/blob/master/3-tiers-app-engine/terraform/app-engine.tf
- This example https://github.com/srikavin/waitlist-watcher/blob/master/terraform/modules/appengine/main.tf

I also posted this on their app engine issue tracker, but they say they won't help troubleshooting terraform projects:
https://issuetracker.google.com/u/3/issues/295518542

Please help me figure out how to troubleshoot this. If it's a permission thing, I was trying to look into the Audit logs to see if somehow terraform had no permissions to to something, but by default nothing is enabled in the Audit logs.

Comment: Did you check the logs? Usually, the error 13 is compilation or runtime error.

Comment: Yes I did. And no I don't see any errors on the Google Cloud Logging. I also tried to turn on terraform debug logging, but nothing interesting is happening besides the error code 13.

Comment: It's not on terraform side, but on Google Cloud Side. Did you also check the logs of Cloud Build?

Comment: This format is more readable:
https://pastebin.com/e7mkk4jV

Comment: Yep, so the container is correctly built but it does not start correctly that cause the error 13. You have to fix the startup problem. Maybe deploy small piece by small piece of code. Or share here what you can share with us.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fixed the error by using a different approach to create a zip file and upload it to the storage bucket, this PR fixed my problem:
https://github.com/Leejjon/ts-appengine-terraform/pull/1/files

I kindly copied this approach from this repository:
https://github.com/Ipsossiapi/pt_streams

I noticed it fails if I don't upload the node_modules folder. Which is a bit weird as when I use the gcloud app deploy command I don't upload the node_modules folder either (I had the node_modules folder ignored in the .gcloudignore file. Apparently the appengine terraform plugin uses the GCP API instead and it works different.